# Django admin site is not showing default permissions of models

Tags: python, django

My Django admin site does not show any default permissions of any models. Actually, I checked the database and I can't find any model permission in the `auth_permissions` table.

I've already run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`. I also tried deleting the database and migration files and run two above command again but doesn't work. I've already registered my models in admin.py.

Any other solutions I can try ?

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .Models import *


# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(LeaveRequest)
admin.site.register(Worker)
admin.site.register(TimeSheet)
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for WorkTime project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os
import rest_framework
import dj_database_url

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
# SECRET_KEY = '0yz04(%a^xuilqa8*@e^e)bj+n%&+jou=tg$%lb&#ox!lk1!x5'
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get(
    'SECRET_KEY', '0yz04(%a^xuilqa8*@e^e)bj+n%&+jou=tg$%lb&#ox!lk1!x5')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG', '') != 'False'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['worktime-management.herokuapp.com', '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'api',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'crispy_forms',
    'web',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'WorkTime.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'WorkTime.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]

# Simplified static file serving.
# https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# Heroku: Update database configuration from $DATABASE_URL.
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

# Media root
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Email config
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('MAIL_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('MAIL_USERNAME')
EMAIL_PORT = 587
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER

# CSRF enable
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True

# Rest Auth
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
}

# Boostrap4
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend', )
```

Comment: Who says Django Admin is supposed to show the "default permissions" of your or any other  model?  What's a default permission?

Comment: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions)

Am I misunderstanding anything in this link ?

Comment: If the default permissions are not showed in django admin site as default then how can I make them showed in admin site. The auth_permission table doesn't have any default permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `admin.py` you are importing all of your models as `from .Model import *`. Python is a case-sensitive programming language if you have not manipulated your `models.py` file as `Models.py`.

I suppose `from .models import *` will do the trick

Comment: Yeah, that works ! Thank you so much. Although, my ```Models``` is actually a folder. I've been trying to divide the models into different files in this folder haha.

Answer (score 1):

The above solution solves the problem. However, my `Models` is actually a folder, I've been trying to divide the models into different files which are stored in that folder. So for those who have the same idea, just simply change the folder's name into `models` and you're good to go :v

Comment: Default permissions are also not generated without errors if you move models into subfolders:
<app>/a/models.py
<app>/b/models.py